# pandas dataframe: is there any way to transform columns as row values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that i want to transform its column to row values if the values is 'Y'

```
Equipment   Component   thin_c02  thin_h20  thin_co
A              A.1          N        N         Y
B              B.1          Y        N         N
C              C.1          N        Y         N
```

I want to turn into

```
Equipment   Component    Reason_corrosion   
A              A.1        thin_co        
B              B.1        thin_co2       
C              C.1        thin_h20
```

do you guys have any ideas?

I have tried df.T but can't transform it in the way that I wanted.

Comment: so the 'Y' values are in the 'thin' columns only? equipment and component are indexes? what happens if there is no 'Y' in the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_fil = df.filter(like='thin')
df['Reason_corrosion'] = (df_fil == 'Y').dot(df_fil.columns)
```

Output:

```
  Equipment Component thin_c02 thin_h20 thin_co Reason_corrosion
0         A       A.1        N        N       Y          thin_co
1         B       B.1        Y        N       N         thin_c02
2         C       C.1        N        Y       N         thin_h20
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your DataFrame is called `df`.

```
columns = ["thin_c02", "thin_h20", "thin_co"]
labels = df[columns].stack()
pd.concat([df, labels[labels=='Y'].reset_index(1)], 1)[['Equipment', 'Component', 'level_1']]
#  Equipment Component   level_1
#0         A       A.1   thin_co
#1         B       B.1  thin_c02
#2         C       C.1  thin_h20
```